# Getting minimum price from other table using left join

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, join, left-join

I am fetching data form two tables, *tour* and *tour_price* using left join, But from pricing table i am not able to fetch *minimum price*.

**Here is my query**

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.tour_title,t2.price 
FROM tours t1 
LEFT JOIN tour_dates t2 ON t1.id=t2.tour_id 
WHERE t1.status = '1' AND ( t2.price between 40 AND 100 ) 
GROUP BY t2.tour_id 
ORDER BY t2.price DESC
```

I think there is minor change i need, but couldn't figure out.

please provide some help.
Thank you.

Comment: use Barmar's comment in your SELECT line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.tour_title, MIN(t2.price) min_price
FROM tours t1
LEFT JOIN tour_dates t2 ON t1.id = t2.tour_id AND t2.price BETWEEN 40 AND 100
WHERE t1.status = '1'
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY min_price DESC
```

- Use `MIN(t2.price)` to get the minimum price.
- Since you're using `LEFT JOIN`, the conditions on the second table should be put in the `ON` clause. Otherwise, the tours that don't have any matching dates will be filtered out, because `t2.price` will be `NULL`.
- Don't use a column from the second table in `GROUP BY`, because it will be `NULL` if there's no match. All the tours with no dates would then be grouped together as one result, which is not what you usually want.

If you don't want the result to include tours with no dates, you should be using `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`. If you're confused about the difference, see

[A Graphical Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Barmar sir, just one last suggestion, i have other conditions too with the query like ratings and facility, so should these criteria comes in the **ON** clause just like BETWEEN you suggested ?

Comment: If they're criteria on the `tour_dates` table they should be in the `ON` clause. If they're criteria on the `tours` table they should be in `WHERE`.

Comment: It's simple to understand: If there's no matching `tour_dates`, everything from that table will be `NULL`, and all comparisons with `NULL` are false (except for `IS NULL`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:***
*This answer is for MS SQL and not for MySQL. Thanx Barmar for the comment.*

Try to use the `MIN()` function on t2.price.

You also need to group by the values that you do a select on except for MIN() because it is a [aggregate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/ms173454.aspx).

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.tour_title, MIN(t2.price )
FROM tours t1 
LEFT JOIN tour_dates t2 ON t1.id=t2.tour_id 
WHERE t1.status = '1' AND ( t2.price between 40 AND 100 ) 
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.tour_title
ORDER BY MIN(t2.price ) DESC
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't require that you put all the other columns in `GROUP BY`. If `t1.id` is a unique ID, as it usually is, grouping by `t1.tour_title` is redundant.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I read the tag like `mssql` and not `mysql`. I will update my answer.